# How to keep active menu item underlined?

Tags: html, css

I'm really new to HTML and CSS. I have a navbar which underlines  the menu item you hover with a fade in, fade out-effect from the middle,
but how can I keep an active menu item underlined with the same style?

I'm also using Typo3 / Fluid which creates me the html code and assigns the "active" class to the active menu item.

This is how it looks like so far: https://jsfiddle.net/wr5w09r0/

css

```
div#top_nav{
    text-align: center;
}

div#top_nav li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 15px;
}

div#top_nav a {

display: inline-block;
position: relative;

}

div#top_nav a:hover{
    color: orange;
}


div#top_nav a:before{

  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;

}

div#top_nav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.active {
    color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Where is the HTML? Is there any Javascript involved in the menu (dynamic loading of content, etc)?

Comment: if possible please share [link](https://jsfiddle.net/) with us, so anyone can easily help you with your current code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this will help you. I have added this simple element.

`div#top_nav a:hover:before , div#top_nav a.active:before`

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

div#top_nav{
 text-align: center;
}

div#top_nav li{
 display: inline;
 padding: 15px;
}



div#top_nav a {

display: inline-block;
position: relative;

}

div#top_nav a:hover{
 color: orange;
}


div#top_nav a:before{

  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;

}

div#top_nav a:hover:before , div#top_nav a.active:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.active {
 color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_nav">
<ul>
<li class="mainMenu-itemLevel1">
<a href="index.php?id=2" class="active">seite1</a></li>
<li class="mainMenu-itemLevel1">
<a href="index.php?id=3">seite2</a>
</li><li class="mainMenu-itemLevel1">
<a href="index.php?id=4">seite3</a></li>
<li class="mainMenu-itemLevel1">
<a href="index.php?id=6">seite4</a></li>
<li class="mainMenu-itemLevel1">
<a href="index.php?id=7">Seite5 lang Hover</a></li>
</ul>


</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. I tried a lot around (should have posted my attempts) and had it almost like you, I just forgot to write div#top_nav behind the comma and wondered why it's not working >.<

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am happy that it is working for you. I have actually the same scenario for my latest project. [HSB](http://hsb.royaltri.com/)

Comment: that's a very nice looking website

Comment: I modified it so that the currently active link is underlined. Is there any way to stop the effect on the currently active link so I don't get 2 lines?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript to do this.

Your javascript would add a class, like `active` to the relevant menu item, and you can then use your css to style it appropriately.

After adding the `active` class to the element, to apply your orange style use this:

```
div#top_nav.active a{
    color: orange;
}
```

Note the addition of `.active` which selects only active items, and the omission of `:hover` on the link, since you no longer care about hover.

You may find the `,` css operator useful here, for applying the same styles to different selectors (active, and hover) as shown in my example below:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
var activeClassName = 'active';

function unselectItems() {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {  
    items[i].classList.remove(activeClassName);
  }
}

function selectItem(item) {
  unselectItems();
  item.classList.add(activeClassName);
}

function onItemClick(event) {
  selectItem(event.target);
}

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {  
  items[i].addEventListener('click', onItemClick);
}
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

span:hover, span.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span class="item">Home</span>
  <span class="item">About</span>
  <span class="item">Contact</span>  
<nav>
```

Comment: The class is a good option, but whether you need Javascript completely depends on how this menu works. If selecting an item just reloads the whole page, then the server just needs to add the class to the active item, and no Javascript is involved at all.

Comment: Adding the active class to the selected menu item is already working. The menu item is already turning its color into orange. I'm just wondering how is it possible to keep the selected menu item underlined with the same underline I defined

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that you already added a class. I've updated my answer.